# Are default values to optional parameters evaluated on every function call?

Tags: function, ocaml, optional-parameters

The [OCaml spec](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/lablexamples.html#sec46) documents the use of default values to optional parameters, but doesn't specify what happens if the default values are e.g. a function that could return a different value each time.

From some testing, it seems like the value is evaluated each time *if* the argument is not passed in; e.g.

```ml
let x = ref 0;;

let incr x =
  x := !x + 1;
  !x
;;

let test ?(a = incr x) () = a;;
```

calling `test ()` results in 1, 2, 3, ..., incrementing each time, but calling `test ~a:123 ()` doesn't increment the ref.

It seems like the behavior of running `test ()` or `test ~a ()` is roughly something like

```ml
let test ?a () =
  let a =
    match a with
    | None -> incr x
    | Some a -> a
  in
  body_of_test ~a ()
;;
```

Is this the right way to model this? And also, is this behavior documented somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed the intended behavior. See from the [documentation](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html#sec139) (emphasis mine):

> A function of the form `fun ? lab :(  pattern =  expr0 ) ->  expr` is equivalent to
>   `fun ? lab :  ident -> let  pattern = match  ident with Some  ident ->  ident | None ->  expr0 in  expr`
>
> where `ident` is a fresh variable, **except that it is unspecified when `expr0` is evaluated**.

Though the evaluation of your increment works as you think it does, it is highly ill-advised to "hide" effects in a function application. Notably, the following code could return either `true` or `false` with no guarantee that another version of the compiler would give the same behavior.

```
let test2 ?(a = incr x) ?(b = incr x) () = a < b
if test2 () then ...
```

Comment: I wonder if the "unspecified" here is weather it is evaluated only once at program start or on every call. Or if the "unspecified" relates to where in the function the `expr0` is evaluated. Could be when the next unnamed argument is bound, when the last argument is bound or on first use inside the function. Might be worth asking for clarification in the documentation.

Comment: To me, the first part of the documentation makes it clear that it is evaluated at every call, just not *when* in the call. I have to admit that the phrasing is dubious, but I'd say it's bad practice to hide impure expressions in optional arguments anyway.

Comment: But oh so tempting for an auto-increment ID.

Comment: Resist the dark side Goswin! :-)

Comment: One can always write the equivalent code of an optional argument manually. That way it is defined how it behaves and when it is evaluated.